# ipad Landscape - Showing a controller which has space on both sides

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape, subview, collectionview

[image]

I have a collection view controller (Blue coloured screen in the image). There is a collection view on it. On click of each of the cell, i want the controller to open like the grey coloured one. This should happen on an iPAD landscape mode. in the potrait mode, the grey coloured screen should occupy the full screen.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: if you will present/push from collection view cell click then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add constraints like these shown in images.

drag vollection view
[image]
add top alignment constraints with respect to view
[image]
same wise set all constraints left right and bottom. and then click the button add constraint at the bottom.
[image]
Here is the final view.
[image]

Now these constraints will be applied regardless of the nature of device and portrait and landscape mode.
If you have any query write in comment. if this served your purpose then accept the answer. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. What we have is a collectionviewcontroller which is again a subclass of lazyloaded core data collection class. You have used a normal view controller here. Is the same thing possible with collectionviewcontroller?